# Is gateaux derivative same as the directional derivative

Tags: derivatives

In the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067149/what-is-difference-between-all-of-these-derivatives), Directional derivative is given as $$D_{\mathbf v}\mathbf g(\mathbf p) := \lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\mathbf g(\mathbf p+\theta\mathbf v)-\mathbf g(\mathbf p)}{\theta} \\ \\ \text{Here v is a unit vector}$$ - which is the same one I studied in high school.

However, I came across this Gateaux Derivative, 
$$ \begin{align*}
\lim_{ \theta \to 0} \frac{F[f+\theta h]- F[f]}{\theta}
\end{align*}
\\ \\ \text{Here h is just a vector}$$

These definitions are so similar. I really cannot appreciate the difference between them. Can someone help me understand this with some simple examples? 
Thank you.

P.S: I am just a beginner and I am not familiar with Banach Spaces and stuff.

Comment: Here is a video that might be useful:  https://youtu.be/jL2tQLvvLG4

Answer (score 2):

They are basically the same thing. Gateaux is between any two locally convex topological vector spaces. Directional derivative is just for  $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$.