# How can we show that the functions are differentiable?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Show that the following functions $$f(x, y)=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\ f(x, y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$$ are differentiable at each point of the domain. Determine which of them is $C^1$.

$$$$

The domain of the functions is $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

How can we show that the functions are differentiable at each point of the domain??

Do we have to find the partial derivatives??

$$$$

**EDIT:**

$$f(x, y)=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}: \\ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-xy\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2x}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y(x^2+y^2)-x^2y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{y^3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)} \\ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=\frac{x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-xy\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x(x^2+y^2)-xy^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}$$

Since the partial derivatives are continuous at $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0)\}$, $f$ is differentiable.

Is this correct??

Could I improve something at the fomrmulation??

Comment: At each point of that domain each of the functions' derivatives of first order exist and are continuous = the function's differentiable at each point of that domain.

Comment: @MaryStar Check the definition?

Comment: @Mary: check whether your functions have *continuous* derivatives of first order.

Comment: Which is the difference to prove that a function is differentiable and to prove that a function is $C^1$ ?? 

$$$$ 

In my book there is the following definition: 

Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. Let's suppose that all the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial{x_j}}$ of $f$ exist and are continuous at a region of a point $x \in U$. Then $f$ is differentiable in $x$.  

We say that a function of which the partial derivatives exist and are continuous are $C^1$. That means that each $C^1$ function is differentiable. @Timbuc

Comment: @MaryStar The paragraph you stated is part definition, part theorem. A $C^1$ function is a function whose first order partials are continuous. And there's a result that says that $C^1$ functions are differentiable.

Comment: And what is the definition that a function is differentiable ?? @GitGud

Comment: @MaryStar You should really check your notes. But you can find the definition [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618937/derivative-of-function-with-2-variables/619010#619010), at the end of the first part of the answer.

Comment: @MaryStar You understood it correctly.

Comment: With this definition it always stands that a differentiable function is also $C^1$, or not?? @GitGud Isn't there a difference between the two meanings??

Comment: @MaryStar No, even with $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ there are well known counter examples.

Comment: So, at the exercise of my initial post do we show the differentiability using the limit defintion and to show that it is $C^1$ we show that the partial derivatives are continuous?? @GitGud

Comment: If they are $C^1$, they are differentiable, you don't need to use the definition for this. You do need to prove that the function is $C^1$, but that's just making the observation that it's the quotient of polynomials.

Comment: Do we say the following:$$f(x, y)=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}: \\ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-xy\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2x}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y(x^2+y^2)-x^2y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{y^3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)} \\ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=\frac{x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-xy\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x(x^2+y^2)-xy^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}$$ 
Since the partial derivatives are continuous at $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0)\}$, $f$ is $C^1$. That implies that $f$ is differentiable. 
$$$$ 
Is this correct?? @GitGud

Comment: @MaryStar It is.

Comment: Could I improve something at the formulation?? @GitGud

Comment: @MaryStar It's fine in my opinion, I would expect full marks.

Comment: If we had a function that wasn't $C^1$ how would we show that it is differentiable?? Using the limit definition?? Or is there aso an other way??

Answer (score 2):

Since $(0,0)$ isn't in the domain, then we don't need to worry about that point. The necessary
 and sufficient conditions for multi-variable differentiation are the existence of all the partials, and their continuity at a given point.

Comment: $C^1$ and differentiable is **not** equivalent

Comment: How come? What is it then?